# Ruby on rails app works locally but does not work on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am doing michael hartl's tutorial for ruby on rails and everything works fine locally but not on heroku when the app deploys.. this problem dint arise before chapter 7 of this book: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#top

are there any details you need to debug this problem? please let me know.....

here are the heroku logs:

```
$ 2012-07-18T06:10:26+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:         <ul class="nav pull-right">

2012-07-18T06:10:26+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined met
hod `find_by_remember_token' for #<Class:0x00000004960740>):
2012-07-18T06:10:26+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:           <li><%= link_to "Home", r
oot_path %></li>
2012-07-18T06:10:26+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:           <li><%= link_to "Help", h
elp_path %></li>
2012-07-18T06:10:26+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:           <% if signed_in? %>
2012-07-18T06:10:26+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:             <li><%= link_to "Users
", users_path %></li>
2012-07-18T06:10:26+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:             <li id="fat-menu" clas
s="dropdown">
2012-07-18T06:10:26+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:               <a href="#" class="d
ropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
2012-07-18T06:10:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:10:in `cu
rrent_user'
2012-07-18T06:10:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:23:in `si
gned_in?'
2012-07-18T06:10:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:1
1:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2533055855927805914_43132200'
2012-07-18T06:10:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:9:in
`_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb__2547305690965663969_41244280'
2012-07-18T06:10:26+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-07-18T06:10:26+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-07-18T06:10:26+00:00 heroku[router]: GET whizcollab.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web
.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=345ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-07-18T06:10:34+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-07-18T06:10:34+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 115.87.214.246 at 2012
-07-18 06:10:34 +0000
2012-07-18T06:10:34+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-07-18T06:10:34+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home a
s HTML
2012-07-18T06:10:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb with
in layouts/application (0.6ms)
2012-07-18T06:10:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
2012-07-18T06:10:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.2ms
)
2012-07-18T06:10:34+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

2012-07-18T06:10:34+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined met
hod `find_by_remember_token' for #<Class:0x00000004960740>):
2012-07-18T06:10:34+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-07-18T06:10:34+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:           <li><%= link_to "Help", h
elp_path %></li>
2012-07-18T06:10:34+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:           <% if signed_in? %>
2012-07-18T06:10:34+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:         <ul class="nav pull-right">

2012-07-18T06:10:34+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:             <li><%= link_to "Users
", users_path %></li>
2012-07-18T06:10:34+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:           <li><%= link_to "Home", r
oot_path %></li>
2012-07-18T06:10:34+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:             <li id="fat-menu" clas
s="dropdown">
2012-07-18T06:10:34+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:               <a href="#" class="d
ropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
2012-07-18T06:10:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:10:in `cu
rrent_user'
2012-07-18T06:10:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:9:in
`_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb__2547305690965663969_41244280'
2012-07-18T06:10:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:23:in `si
gned_in?'
2012-07-18T06:10:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:1
1:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2533055855927805914_43132200'
2012-07-18T06:10:34+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-07-18T06:10:34+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-07-18T06:10:34+00:00 heroku[router]: GET whizcollab.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web
.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=22ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-07-18T06:12:03+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-07-18T06:12:03+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-07-18T06:12:03+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 115.87.214.246 at 2012
-07-18 06:12:03 +0000
2012-07-18T06:12:03+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home a
s HTML
2012-07-18T06:12:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb with
in layouts/application (0.7ms)
2012-07-18T06:12:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
2012-07-18T06:12:03+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms

2012-07-18T06:12:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.3ms
)
2012-07-18T06:12:03+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined met
hod `find_by_remember_token' for #<Class:0x00000004960740>):
2012-07-18T06:12:03+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-07-18T06:12:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:         <ul class="nav pull-right">

2012-07-18T06:12:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:           <li><%= link_to "Home", r
oot_path %></li>
2012-07-18T06:12:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:           <li><%= link_to "Help", h
elp_path %></li>
2012-07-18T06:12:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:           <% if signed_in? %>
2012-07-18T06:12:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:             <li id="fat-menu" clas
s="dropdown">
2012-07-18T06:12:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:             <li><%= link_to "Users
", users_path %></li>
2012-07-18T06:12:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:               <a href="#" class="d
ropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
2012-07-18T06:12:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:10:in `cu
rrent_user'
2012-07-18T06:12:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:23:in `si
gned_in?'
2012-07-18T06:12:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:9:in
`_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb__2547305690965663969_41244280'
2012-07-18T06:12:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:1
1:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2533055855927805914_43132200'
2012-07-18T06:12:03+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-07-18T06:12:03+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-07-18T06:12:03+00:00 heroku[router]: GET whizcollab.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web
.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=17ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-07-18T06:13:31+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-07-18T06:13:31+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-07-18T06:13:31+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 115.87.214.246 at 2012
-07-18 06:13:31 +0000
2012-07-18T06:13:31+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home a
s HTML
2012-07-18T06:13:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb with
in layouts/application (0.4ms)
2012-07-18T06:13:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
2012-07-18T06:13:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.9ms
)
2012-07-18T06:13:31+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

2012-07-18T06:13:31+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-07-18T06:13:31+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined met
hod `find_by_remember_token' for #<Class:0x00000004960740>):
2012-07-18T06:13:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:         <ul class="nav pull-right">

2012-07-18T06:13:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:           <li><%= link_to "Home", r
oot_path %></li>
2012-07-18T06:13:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:           <% if signed_in? %>
2012-07-18T06:13:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:             <li id="fat-menu" clas
s="dropdown">
2012-07-18T06:13:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:             <li><%= link_to "Users
", users_path %></li>
2012-07-18T06:13:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:           <li><%= link_to "Help", h
elp_path %></li>
2012-07-18T06:13:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:               <a href="#" class="d
ropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
2012-07-18T06:13:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:10:in `cu
rrent_user'
2012-07-18T06:13:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:23:in `si
gned_in?'
2012-07-18T06:13:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:1
1:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2533055855927805914_43132200'
2012-07-18T06:13:31+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-07-18T06:13:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:9:in
`_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb__2547305690965663969_41244280'
2012-07-18T06:13:31+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-07-18T06:13:31+00:00 heroku[router]: GET whizcollab.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web
.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=22ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-07-18T06:13:37+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-07-18T06:13:37+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-07-18T06:13:37+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users" for 115.87.214.246 at
 2012-07-18 06:13:37 +0000
2012-07-18T06:13:37+00:00 heroku[router]: GET whizcollab.herokuapp.com/users dyn
o=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=47ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-07-18T06:13:37+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#index as HTM
L
2012-07-18T06:13:37+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

2012-07-18T06:13:37+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-07-18T06:13:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:10:in `cu
rrent_user'
2012-07-18T06:13:37+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `find_by_r
emember_token' for #<Class:0x00000004960740>):
2012-07-18T06:13:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:23:in `si
gned_in?'
2012-07-18T06:13:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:48:i
n `signed_in_user'
2012-07-18T06:13:37+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-07-18T06:13:37+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Comment: You can start with outputting what happens on Heroku, and what should happen.

Comment: herokuapp only shows this error on all pages "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

Comment: how i post heroku logs on here from cmd? it would look messy if i just copy it..please guide me :)

Comment: It depends on the operating system. If on osx: `heroku logs | pbcopy`, if on Linux: `heroku logs | xclip`

Comment: i added the heroku logs above :)

Comment: Now it's the time to paste your session_helper.rb

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I was also doing the Hart Tutorial and was coming into the SAME issue. I ran the heroku run db:migrate....i made sure it was up to date with git push heroku....I added a remember_key to my one user in the database. It was in the schema.rb file.

I finally found the answer:

user.rb:

add :remember_token to attr_accessible

Ex: "attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_token"

For some reason this is left out of the tutorial, even though now that i know whats wrong it makes sense. After adding this I re-pushed to heroku and Viola....

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I just realized that my answer is the complicated version of Teoulas's comment "or you simply don't have that attribute" -- credit where credit is deserved :)

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic finders only work if the attribute you're searching for exists. Either you didn't run all migrations or you simply don't have that attribute (remember_token) or you misspelled it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I've to say that IMHO it is not necessary to add  `:remember_token`
to the `attr_accessible` field. Doing that you expose the `:remember_token`, creating getters and setters, which is not necessary since `:remember_token` has to be considered as an internal variable. I solved the problem restarting the Heroku app, as confirmed here:

[heroku-nomethod-error-remember-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527892/heroku-nomethod-error-remember-token)

After rebooting the app was working correctly, as it was doing locally.

Comment: This worked brilliantly for me, thank you! (And I do agree that you shouldn't expose your `:remember_token`. It should be pointed out that it's not an error/omission on Hartl's part.)

Comment: just run `heroku restart`

Answer (score 1):

It fails because it does not find the definition of the following method `find_by_remember_token`. I remember that `remember_token` is defined in the `session_helper`in the Hartl tutorial. It seems to arise when the `signed_in?` method is called.

Could you paste the `session_helper.rb` and `User` model code?

Answer (score 1):

Try running `heroku restart`. It did the trick for me.

It should be noted that adding `:remembered_token` to your `attr_accessible` declaration is not recommended, as per [r4m's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15344976/850548). (There's a reason Hartl didn't do that in the tutorial.)

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `find_by_remember_token' for #<Class:0x00000004960740>):
```

is telling you that Rails doesn't know what 'find_by_remember_token' is, which means that it either doesn't exist (i.e it's a typo), or that the database, which is generally used to determine class properties, isn't aware of this field.

Assuming it's not a typo, then migrating your database would be an option:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the internal server error when I tried to push to heroku and also to amazon.  I had to precompile my assets before pushing the app to the server.  If this is your problem the easiest solution was to run

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

or add 
    load 'deploy/assets' 
to the capfile, if you are using Capistrano.  I was told you can add the following to your deploy.rb file, but I was not able to get it working.

```
after "deploy:restart", "deploy:precompile"

  namespace :deploy do

    desc "Compile assets"
    task :precompile, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{release_path} && rake RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} assets:precompile"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was defining the create_remember_token method in the User model exactly as described in the tutorial.

```
private
def create_remember_token
   self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end
```

And then calling it in the before_save method.

```
before_save { 
    self.email.downcase!
    create_remember_token
}
```

I didn't have it as a method declaration before. And while it worked on my computer, it failed in Heroku.

```
#this failed in Heroku    
before_save { 
    self.email.downcase!
    self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
}
```

Also, it would do no harm to run:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```